# Why are edits that enforce site policy rejected?

Tags: support, editing

The Stack Exchange has a policy against [tags in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/173448).

Why are edits [that enforce site policy](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/299466) rejected?

Comment: I don't believe there's any standing order to reject that sort of edit. Do you have a specific example you can link to? My guess, without having seen the edit, is that it was rejected for other reasons, such as the edit being too minor to really improve the post. If a reviewer is unaware of that "no tags in the title" policy (from 5 years ago), they could very easily choose to reject an edit only to the title, especially if other issues in the question remained unaddressed.

Comment: @Excell - see https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/299466. Sorry for not including it with the question. I was trying to avoid meta effects.

Comment: It looks like that's exactly what happened. I went ahead and edited the title. There really wasn't anything majorly wrong with the question, as far as I could see.

Comment: @Excell - thanks. I really don't have any point on Super User, so all about I can do is police questions at the moment.

Comment: Tbh i would've made it fit the sentence, I.e. instead of "Windows 8.1 [blah]" I would've made it "[blah] in Windows 8.1". But that's just me

Comment: @Robotnik yeah precisely

Comment: Yeah I'm going to go out on a branch here and say that taking the windows 8.1 out of the title wasn't necessary. I think the tag thing is mostly like - "Help me figure out this worksheet function - excel 2007 2010 2013 vba horseshoes"